# Make Javafx/Scenebuilder recognize tagged fields and methods when splitting the MainController into multiple files?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to put the logic for the menubar of my program in another file, so that my MainController is not as big and cluttered.
 I created Menucontroller.java but Scenebuilder doesn't recognize any Fields or Methods.

I am not trying to create a new controller with its own fxml file.
I want to split up my MainControllers logic, the code works fine inside the MainController and gets recognized.

I wasn't able to find how to do this anywhere.
Could someone tell me what the appropriate steps are so that the MenuController can be used?

MainController.java:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private void calculate() {
        System.out.println(""Works.)
        }
```

MenuController.java:
^This gets recognized and works by assigning calculate in Scenebuilder as the action for a button.

```
package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;

public class MenuController {

    @FXML MenuBar fxMenuBar;
    @FXML Menu fxFileMenu;
        @FXML MenuItem fxExitItem;
    @FXML Menu fxEditMenu;
    @FXML Menu fxHelpMenu;

    @FXML
    private void exit(ActionEvent fxExitItem) {
        System.out.println("Exit function called.");
    }
}
```

^This does not. In Scenebuilder I dont get a prompt in the action field for the exit-function, nor any prompt in the ID-Fields for the Menuitems to assign the fxVariables.

Comment: As stated in the answer below, each FXML file can have only one controller. If your controller is large enough that you want to split it into smaller components, you should probably consider splitting the FXML into smaller components as well. You can assemble the components in a single FXML file using `<fx:include>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One FXML file can only have one Controller so @FXML will only be recognized in that one controller. If you wish to split up the code then have to get all the javafx elements in the controller and then pass them like normal java objects to the other file.
for example:

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML MenuBar bar;
    @FXML Menu menu;


    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        MenuController mc = new MenuController(bar, menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I can live with the fields still being inside the MainController, but what about methods? Most of them will also need to have a tag, but If I have to declare the methods inside the MainController as well, then it basically defeats the purpose of what Im trying to do. Is it just not possible without creating another view/fxml?

Comment: I now realize that I could make "proxy"-methods by declaring the method inside MainController with the tag, and inside the method call the true method inside MenuController. But I think this makes it just more confusing for future developers.

Comment: @MaxK.Yea thats pretty much the only way to do it as far as I know. I dont bother to split it I just put in as much effort as possible to keep the Controllers clean, and methods short and descriptive so that it stays organised even if its over 800 lines.